# How can I save an open text file in a GUI console from a text console?

Tags: xorg, gedit

I'm running the latest desktop Ubuntu, and my system seems to have frozen -- the pointer moves when I move the mouse, but nothing else is happening; even the clock is stopped. `tty1`-`6` work just fine, though; it's just the GUI.

Normally I'd just restart, but I have an open file in gedit with a lot of unsaved changes -- inexplicably, the auto-save hasn't worked for ages. Is there a way to go into another console, log in with the same account, and access processes in a GUI console, either to just send a "save" command or just retrieve the open file text?

**ETA:** I know how to get the process ID with `lsof` and have done so. I suspect there may be something I can do with `disown` or the like.

Comment: You can look to see if it saved  a backup, `ls -A`, you should (hopefully) see a file.txt~. Otherwise, I do not know a solution, I would debug why autosave is not working.

Comment: I didn't think to mention, but while there IS a file.txt~, it's older than the file.txt.

Comment: check the contents. `nano file.txt~`

Comment: Further clarification: The _contents_ are older than the main file. I checked before I ever posted this question.

Comment: I do not think there is any way to recover then.

Comment: 1. In order to recover it would require that Gedit implements a safe exit (while saving files) from a certain signal (Say, SIGUSR1 or SIGTSTP). Short of browsing its code, I doubt this to be the case. 2. You can only disown a process from an attached console (which, in your case, exists under the GUI). However, disowning it leaves no way to control it other than OS signals.

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes